# Form which includes different models in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I'm new with Yii2 framework, so. I have created 4 tables in my database and generated 4 models according to the tables. Now I need to create 1 form, which includes information of all 4 tables.

F.e  `Sale` table containts information of `sale code` and `Category` table contains information of `category name`. I need to create a form in which I could enter all the information and it would store in a different tables according to the information.

Here is my `SiteController action` :

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $category = new Category();
    $sale = new Sale();

    if ($category && $sale->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($category && $sale->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['create']);
        }
    }
    return $this->render('create', [
        'category' => $category,
        'sale' => $sale,
    ]);
}
```

And here is my `Create` view:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $category app\models\Category */
/* @var $form ActiveForm */
?>
<div class="site-create">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($category, 'name') ?>
    <?= $form->field($sale, 'code') ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Submit'), ['class' => 'btn 
btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any help

Comment: There is lack of information in your post. Why do you have 4 tables? How are the tables related to each other? What would you achieve with this code? My advice: use [gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html) to generate your skeleton code. Set up the relations. Then go further.

Comment: I set `foreign keys` in my database. It doesn't matter you have 4 or 40 tables, the principle is the same

Comment: Yeah, for sure. Do you set up your models correctly? Paste the relevant parts.

Comment: My `models` are default, which was generated in `Model Generator`, I haven't changed anything there

Answer (score 1):

Change in SiteController action :

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $category = new Category();
    $sale = new Sale();

    // load request parameters for both category and sale model
    if ($category->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $sale->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($category->save() && $sale->save()) { // saving both model
            return $this->redirect(['create']);
        }
    }
    return $this->render('create', [
        'category' => $category,
        'sale' => $sale,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: This isn't working. Only `$category` inserted into the database.. :(

Comment: Sale model data not inserted ?? May be error in validation. Try :         $category->save(false) && $sale->save(false)

Comment: With $category->save(false) && $sale->save(false) i get this error now: http://imageshack.com/a/img923/2373/OO28S3.png

Comment: Check out [Working with Relational Data](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data). You have to save the foreign key manually or use the [link() method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#link()-detail). The error is pretty obvious, you have another relation to your item table. Anyway, at this point, you have not provide us with all information that we need to help you.